# Is it possible for a kafka connect producer to write on multiple partitions with connector SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I use this connector com.github.jcustenborder.kafka.connect.spooldir.SpoolDirCsvSourceConnector on kafka connect with a 12 partition topic.

My CSV input file is a 1.6M line file (~ 850 MB).

I've noticed that during the 5h of the ingestion... My producer only uses only 1 partition.

I suppose it is not possible to modify this behavior with a unique file in input ?

The documentation says :

task.partitioner

The task partitioner implementation is used when the connector is configured to use more than one task. This is used by each task to identify which files will be processed by that task. This ensures that each file is only assigned to one task.

Would it be smart, at least to increase throughput, to split this big file in 1000 files before moving them to the input folder  to be able to use more partition on the cluster ?

Comment: Where's the data in the files coming from? Could whatever wrote the CSV file just write the data to Kafka directly instead?

Comment: Not a specific answer, but the partition that is written to is not exactly hard-coded as using only one partition - https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/jcustenborder/kafka/connect/spooldir/AbstractSourceTask.java#L293

Comment: Provider sends me one file per day through file transfer. It seems I can't share this load on the 12 partitions available. I'll try to split that file modulo 12 and add some tasks on the connector to the if I have better performance.